# Clarify RSA SAML Response

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, saml-2.0

Is not so clear to me how to check and parse value passed by this partial response envelope in SAML 2.0:

```
<dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <dsig:SignedInfo><dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments"/><dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <dsig:Reference URI="#ID_ce8c62aa-08e4-4a21-a89a-af4fbd7a9f50">
            <dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <dsig:DigestValue>ImUVGjTf7WTCmboAbAtjx7WKQhI=</dsig:DigestValue>
        </dsig:Reference>
    </dsig:SignedInfo>
    <dsig:SignatureValue>CDk+O/3PPh57l84pjFW0xwiPYJ+yinYJciBowT3nkPaAXeMYCH1AopZl7ZP+swPiK+oYuW9STPSlJVuEuDao5VbSU2WlQR7Ed9nZMt9PNY19/eKtkAqbMk01ZY8YH6OyTQm17w6IzNRbY4sJcHSRz9eDUsTzAYVhV9PEBgT1ouZsghklMCe0iYBjK5LmRS88jGmCN5sZ5+L8+KimTCakWSJ8CLntEAFx1SBL50Or4e8j6nHiW7g==</dsig:SignatureValue>
    <dsig:KeyInfo>
        <dsig:KeyValue>
            <dsig:RSAKeyValue>
                <dsig:Modulus>4Gvzu2dCYGhdWr9Er/WtgbWRqAR798IPCfAubx8NeBKG/X6P7sM91zbD2LEH4tJS2vkMCnQFidoLdeh1SHp7+GLHnVsgTcj6NPOit0EOHz10tdRmFMwoRCh5hcMFEisFUgSdaS8bO2wSXBmLENfLDUOSYKKLP0JGtTqnAZ0A99UNrVWKemx/EnHopH+Q7M+zmbj8VWFVlCK6rDfXJLUBr+kGSlw==</dsig:Modulus>
                <dsig:Exponent>AQAB</dsig:Exponent>
            </dsig:RSAKeyValue>
        </dsig:KeyValue>
    </dsig:KeyInfo>
</dsig:Signature>
```

So basically the `RSAKeyValue` should contain the "public key" to read the `DigestedValue`?
So what's the purpose of the `Signature` value?

I would like to implement a Java class to decrypt (I have the proper keystore and pass to do that...). Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: This is a signature, not an encrypted value.  Digest value is a hash of the elements and values refered in the Reference element. Signature is an RSA signature of the hash. That way you can validate the XML was signed by trusted party (or not).

Comment: To decrypt SAML assertions you may check other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674646/how-to-decrypt-encryptedassertion-manually

Comment: "Signature is an RSA signature of the hash." you mean SignatureValue?
so DigestValue is an hash of Reference content and SignatureValue the hash of DigestValue? Can u clearify? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comment, it's an [XML signature](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/). The signature allows you to validate the XML has been signed by a trusted party and the element hasn't been modified. So you can trust the SAML response is really from the IdP you can trust. It is not encryption.

> I would like to implement a Java class to decrypt

As I stated there's nothing to decrypt, you can only validate integrity of the signed XML element.

For that I suggest you use an out of box library to process the XML (it will be boring to implement all canonization options, etc..). I suggest you use an out of box library ( OpenSAML, spring-security-saml2) to validate the signature.

if you want to do it yourself, just read [search/about](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html) the XML signatures.

What you have there:

`<dsig:Reference URI="#ID_ce8c62aa-08e4-4a21-a89a-af4fbd7a9f50">`

There must be an element in your XML with id attribute of `"#ID_ce8c62aa-08e4-4a21-a89a-af4fbd7a9f50"` and the signature ensures integrity of the refered XML element. Make sure the signature is refered to the whole SAML message or an assertion element. If not, you're code would be prone to *signature injection attacks*. That's why I suggest you use a mature library for that.

`<dsig:DigestValue>ImUVGjTf7WTCmboAbAtjx7WKQhI=</dsig:DigestValue>`

RSA doesn't work with messages of arbitrary (any) length, so a message digest (sha-1 hash) is created and that is signed. The `DigestValue` is value of the hash created from the signed XML element and its content. (how to create a whole content to be hashed is depending on the parameters stated in the CanonicalizationMethod, Transforms, DigestMethod, you can read about it in the first link)

`<dsig:SignatureValue>`

This is the RSA/PKCS1.5 signature of the DigestValue

I hope that clarifies your question.